# How to show details of active cell ina a lable component of appdesigner in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer, matlab-uitable

[image]I have created an app.UITable  I choose A1(cell(1,1)) as the default active cell and I want to show it in a Lable and change it by some inputs.
I tried :

```
    function UITableCellSelection(app, event)
        indices = event.Indices;
        app.SelectedCells = indices;
        app.activecellLabel.Text = app.SelectedCells
```

but it doesn't display anything.
How can I set my active cell and display it in a Lable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the content of a table cell, not just the indices.

```
function UITableCellSelection(app, event)
    indices = event.Indices;
    app.SelectedCells = indices;
    app.activecellLabel.Text = app.UITable.Data{ indices(1), indices(2)};
```

Comment: I tried this but again it didn't display anything. I am editing my question by entering a photo.

Comment: where should I add it??

Comment: Right after app.activecellLabel.Text = app.UITable.Data{ indices(1), indices(2)};